# combine predicates into expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am aiming to use this signature:

```
IEnumerable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
```

and would like to AND these 2 predicates:

```
Func<Employee, bool> isActiveEmployee = e => e.DateFired == null;
Func<Employee, bool> isNewEmployee = e => e.DateHired >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90);
```

into an expression. How can I achieve this please?

PS:

Basically, I am trying to use [this](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2013/05/orms-don-reinvent-wheel.html). But the line:

```
var body = (BinaryExpression) expression.Body;
```

in method `GetDynamicQuery` taken from [here](https://github.com/bbraithwaite/RepoWrapper/blob/master/DynamicQuery.cs) throws an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression'.

Using this approach:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> isActiveEmployee = e => e.DateFired == null;
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> isNewEmployee = e => e.DateHired >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90);

Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> combined_expression = e => isActiveEmployee.Invoke(e) && isNewEmployee.Invoke(e);
```

Comment: `Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> ex = em=>isActiveEmployee(em) && isNewEmployee(em)`

Comment: fair enough - that was easy (-: is my question unworthy an answer?

Comment: Are you going to use the expression with entity framework or linq to SQL...?

Comment: Can you show how are you using the expression? The reason I am asking is that if your expression needs to be translate to SQL, then invoking methods inside the expressions will not work and you need another solution.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, and this solution can be change: `Func<Employee, bool>` to `Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>`

Comment: @Grundy, If the expressions contains a method invocation, then the data access framework would throw an exception when it tries to translate the expression to SQL

Comment: @csetzkorn, take a look at the second part of my answer where I suggest to use the `Expand` method on the generated expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you need a real expression that can be translated to SQL by the many data access frameworks.

One solution is to use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) like this:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> isActiveEmployee = e => e.DateFired == null;
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> isNewEmployee = e => e.DateHired >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90);

Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> combined_expression = e => isActiveEmployee.Invoke(e) && isNewEmployee.Invoke(e);
```

Then you can wrap your `IQueryable` using the `AsExpandable` method from LinqKit like this:

```
var query = context.Employees.AsExpandable().Where(combined_expression);
```

Or, if you don't want to invoke `AsExpandable`, you can expand the new expression and then use it like any other expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> combined_expression = e => isActiveEmployee.Invoke(e) && isNewEmployee.Invoke(e);

combined_expression = combined_expression.Expand();

var query = context.Employees.Where(combined_expression);
```

**UPDATE:**

For the second example you provided, you can do this:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> expression1 = e => e.Guid == new Guid("28D3BCFB-9472-4141-BD88-BE5E7E1230F0");

Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> expression2 = e => e.Guid == new Guid("0F0DBA45-F842-4E46-9ED4-F50B5BCF0509");

Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> combined_expression = e => expression1.Invoke(e) || expression2.Invoke(e);

combined_expression = combined_expression.Expand();

// use combined_expression
```

Comment: Did you install the LinqKit nuget package? `Expand` is an extension method from LinqKit, did you include the `LinqKit` namespace (via `using LinqKit`)?

Comment: Thanks. Getting there. Now getting: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression'.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to match what you have done so far?

Comment: I think this would be too confusing. I am sorry - might be better to delete

Comment: What do you mean better to delete? Delete what?

Comment: Sorry I meant my question ... I appreciate your answer.

Comment: This is what I am actually after: e => e.Guid == new Guid("28D3BCFB-9472-4141-BD88-BE5E7E1230F0") || e.Guid == new Guid("0F0DBA45-F842-4E46-9ED4-F50B5BCF0509") I was just using the above as a simplified example

Comment: I tried this but it does not work either with this code: https://github.com/bbraithwaite/RepoWrapper/blob/master/DynamicQuery.cs

Comment: If you try the full expression `e => e.Guid == new Guid("28D3BCFB-9472-4141-BD88-BE5E7E1230F0") || e.Guid == new Guid("0F0DBA45-F842-4E46-9ED4-F50B5BCF0509")` directly without combining the parts, would it work?

Comment: yes tried this as well and e => e.Guid == Guid.Parse("28D3BCFB-9472-4141-BD88-BE5E7E1230F0") || e.Guid == Guid.Parse("0F0DBA45-F842-4E46-9ED4-F50B5BCF0509")

Comment: So, using the full expression works but composing it from parts doesn't? Strange.

Comment: So the problem is not with combining the expressions which is what your question is about.